# How to specify } (Closing brace) in boost regular expression?

Tags: c++, boost-regex, widestring

I am using boost 1.54 library in my program. My task is to expand some patterns in a string.

One such instance is if a closing brace `}` is found in the string replace it with `>`

I had written the following regex in my code.

```
boost::wregex rightbrace(L"\}"); // replace this by >

strText = boost::regex_replace(strText, rightbrace, L">");
```

My code is compiling fine. But my program crashes when it encounters the first statement it crashes with the following exception

> Unhandled exception at 0x7599c41f in Compress.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > @ 0x0018fa54

Since `}` is a special symbol I have escaped it with `\` symbol.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

You've escaped the `}` for boost, but you need to escape the `\` escape char for the compiler as well.

```
boost::wregex rightbrace(L"\\}");
```